# Update inverse of cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, matrix-equations

I have a problem where I have a matrix $\bf{A}$ which is non-square, I compute the cross product ($\bf{B} = \bf{A}^T * \bf{A}$), and then invert the symmetric matrix $\bf{B}$ to get $\bf{B}^{-1}$. Then $\bf{A}$ is updated by having the first row removed and a new final row added. This has to be done many times, so I am wondering whether I have missed something about how to compute $\bf{B}^{-1}$ directly from knowing the new row in $\bf{A}$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$ for $n<m$, and that $B = A^TA$
is invertible.

Let {$e_k$} be the standard base vectors for ${\mathbb R}^m$, and define the upshift matrix
$$\eqalign{
 &U = [\,e_m\,\,e_1\,\,e_2 \ldots e_{m-1}\,] \cr
 &U^{-1} = U^T \cr
}$$
The product $(UA)$ shifts the rows of $A$ upward and moves the first row to the last row.

The first row of $A$ is given (as a column vector) by:  $\,\,a=A^Te_1$

The replacement row is given by the (column) vector:  $\,\,v$

Their difference is the vector:  $\,\,w = (v-a)$

The updated $A$ matrix is: $\,\,Z = UA + e_mw^T$

Let $Y$ denote the updated $B$ matrix, which can be calculated as 
$$\eqalign{
  Y &= Z^TZ \cr
    &= A^TU^TUA + A^TU^Te_mw^T + we_m^TUA + we_m^Te_mw^T \cr
    &= A^TA + A^Te_1w^T + we_1^TA + ww^T \cr
    &=  B + aw^T + wa^T + ww^T \cr
    &=  B + vw^T + wa^T \cr
}$$
To calculate the inverse of $Y\,$ apply the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to the following sequence of matrices
$$\eqalign{
  X &=  B + vw^T \cr
  Y &=  X + wa^T \cr
}$$
which will look something like this
$$\eqalign{
   X^{-1} &= B^{-1} - \tfrac{B^{-1}vw^TB^{-1}}{1+w^TB^{-1}v} \cr
   Y^{-1} &= X^{-1} - \tfrac{X^{-1}wa^TX^{-1}}{1+a^TX^{-1}w} \cr
}$$

Comment: Since $(vw^T+wa^T)=(vv^T-aa^T),\,$ you can rewrite the final few steps as $$\eqalign{
  Y &=  B + vv^T - aa^T \cr
  X &=  B + vv^T \implies
   X^{-1} &= B^{-1} - \tfrac{B^{-1}vv^TB^{-1}}{1+v^TB^{-1}v} \cr
  Y &=  X - aa^T \implies
   Y^{-1} &= X^{-1} + \tfrac{X^{-1}aa^TX^{-1}}{1-a^TX^{-1}a} \cr
}$$